# Facing Connection Timeout issue in oneplus device

Tags: android

I request your expertise suggestion / recommendation in the issue that we are facing in some of oneplus devices(HD1901OnePlus,GM1901OnePlus,ONEPLUS A6010OnePlus) with Android 10 OS. Below is our scenario:
We are attempting a Server communication with "HttpsURLConnection" object and in some of the one plus devices with Android 10 OS we are encountering an "java.net.ConnectException" as follows
`java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to xxx.yyy.co.in/xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxx.`
I need your support in understanding the root-cause why there is a frequent time out connection pbm in Android 10 devices.

Thanks in advance.
Appreciate your support at the earliest.

Comment: Any clue on this? facing similar issue here